# Pylint Syntax Error Despite Code Functionality

Tags: python, pylint

I got a weird situation where Pylint is flagging a "syntax-error" in the last line of the following code snippet, even though the code seems to be working as expected for my tests.

```
    if n>2:
        for i in range(0,n):
            print(check_prime(i), end = " ")
```

Can someone help me understand why Pylint is raising this error? Is there an issue with my code or is it possibly a false positive from Pylint?
Any reasons as to why this happens?

Comment: The way I'm looking is fine, but I think the error is due to indentation. Use tabs instead of spaces if this is the case.

Comment: helps if you show more of the code.  you have places which don't use the preferred spacing style n>2 should be n > 2, range(0,n) should have a space after the comma, end = something should have no spaces.  pylint will grumble, but should not report a syntax error.

Comment: @M.R. don't use **tab**. Definitely not recommended. Use 4-spaces instead. https://pep8.org/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I told that for this problem because sometimes chasing number of spaces is not good idea.Are you going to count spaces for a 4 indent code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clearly a Python 3 code (one can see that because you use the *print* function).

But, if you run PyLint installed on a Python 2 virtualenv, you get an error:

```
************* Module ...
E: 11, 0: invalid syntax (<string>, line 11) (syntax-error)
```

To solve that, you need a Python 3 [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/venv.html).

```
python -m venv my_projet
source my_project/bin/activate
pip install pylint
pylint path/to/my_file.py
```